# How to configure pom for StrutsTestCase so that web.xml is found?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, struts-1

I'm using Maven 2 to build a Java - Sturts 1.2 - Spring 1.2 project. I'm trying to incorporate the StrutsTestCase extension of JUnit to allow testing of action classes.

When I try to build, I get the following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: The /WEB-INF/web.xml was not found.
  at servletunit.struts.MockStrutsTestCase.getActionServlet(MockStrutsTestCase.java:344)
  at servletunit.struts.MockStrutsTestCase.tearDown(MockStrutsTestCase.java:130)
```

In researching this, I've learned the following:

1. If your `web.xml` file is in a non-standard location, then `setServletConfigFile()` can be used to indicate to `StrutsTestCase` where the file is.
2. When building with Maven, it may be necessary to indicate what resources should be included in the `pom.xml`.

I'm trying to implement this, here is my current progress:

Test class:

```
import servletunit.struts.MockStrutsTestCase;

public class FooActionTest extends MockStrutsTestCase {

  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  super.setUp();
  setServletConfigFile("webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
}

public void testTest() throws Exception { /* stub, no content */ }
```

I have included the following `testResources` in the `build` tag in the `pom.xml`.

```
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </testResource>
  <testResource>
    <directory>webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Here is the structure of the project:

```
myproject
│---src
│   |---main
|   |   |---java
|   |
|   |---test
|       |---Java
|
|---target
|   |---classes
|   |
|   |---MYPROJECT
|       |---META-INF
|       |---WEB-INF
|           |---struts.config.xml
|           |---web.xml
|
|---webapp
|   |---META-INF
|   |---WEB-INF
|       |---struts.config.xml
|       |---web.xml
|---pom.xml
```

Of course, I've tried a variety of variations of the paths in `pom.xml` and in `setServletConfigFile`. I've also tried using `setContextDirectory`, with no different result.

Comment: What happens when `webapp` is moved to `src/main/webapp` following Maven conventions?

Comment: OK, I tried that, but it didn't help. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the default Maven webapp structure

```
myproject
|---src
|   |---main
|   |   |---java
|   |
|   |---test
|   |    |---Java
|   |
|   |---webapp
|        |---WEB-INF
|             |---struts.config.xml
|             |---web.xml
|
|---pom.xml
```

I'm adding webapp XML files to my test resources and I **don't need to call setServletConfigFile method**.

```
<project>
...
<build>
...
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
..
</build>
...
</project>
```

So, in your case, you should add these lines in your POM file :

```
<project>
...
<build>
...
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
..
</build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: I realize that this question is only 10 months old, but I'm in no position to evaluate your answer, having no access to the codebase in question. So I won't vote or accept, but perhaps others will appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is through property that holds a path to `web.xml`.

This way you can simply pass the property value to surefire plugin

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <test.web-xml.file>${project.build.directory}/MYPROJECT/WEB-INF/web.xml</test.web-xml.file>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then in your setup method just get a system property:

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    // You may want to do some validation if this property is set and
    // points to a file
    setServletConfigFile( System.getProperty("test.web-xml.file") );
  }
```

Comment: I hadn't been using the surefire-plugin previously. I tried adding this, but it didn't successfully add a system property. But even _that_ had worked, I'm not able to get `setServletConfigFile` to work with a String literal. Questions of how to pass a value to this method are secondary.