# How to determine what resources are available for tests using Maven?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

The context for my problem is given here: [How to configure pom for StrutsTestCase so that web.xml is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070611/how-to-configure-pom-for-strutstestcase-so-that-web-xml-is-found)

In my `pom.xml` I have included the following, with hopes of making various files available during tests:

```
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </testResource>
  <testResource>
    <directory>webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

My expectation is that everything in `src/test/java` will be available during tests, as will be `web.xml`, `struts-config.xml` in `webapp/WEB-INF`.

The `web.xml` file is not being found during tests. In troubleshooting this I have two problems.

1. I'm not completely sure where I am (or should be) telling my other code to look for `web.xml`
2. I have no idea how to verify that `web.xml` is available while tests are being run.

For now, I'm asking #2. How can I verify that the XML above is doing what I think it should, and making `web.xml` available for use in tests?

Comment: You indicated that you want to make the "`pom.xml` available for use in tests"? Is that accurate, or are you only interested in `web.xml`, `struts-config.xml`, and other web content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your configuration may be that you've included the "`WEB-INF`" as part of your `<testResource>`. What you probably want is something more like this:

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>webapp</directory>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

(Or, if you're using the [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080748/how-to-determine-what-resources-are-available-for-tests-using-maven/7082818#comment-8493376), the `directory` would instead be `src/main/webapp`.)

And, if you only want to include XML files in the WEB-INF directory, then you'll need some additional "`includes`" config:

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>webapp</directory>
    </testResource>
    <includes>
        <include>WEB-INF/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
</testResources>
```

In order to *test* that these files are actually available on the classpath during your test runs, you can do something like follows:

```
URL webXml = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/web.xml");
assumeNotNull(webXml);
```

(As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080748/how-to-determine-what-resources-are-available-for-tests-using-maven/7082818#answer-7082818), the use of [`assumeNotNull`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeNotNull(java.lang.Object...)) is optional.)

Comment: Beautiful. That change to the pom was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the deployment descriptors (i.e `web.xml`, `struts-config.xml`, etc.) on the test *classpath* itself (e.g. to be be looked up via `classloader.getResource*`), then there should be no need for you to add or modify the `testResources` in the POM. Try simply looking up the file in your test setup as follows:

```
File file = new File("webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
assumeTrue(file.exists());
```

*(Note: The use of* [`assumeTrue`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeTrue%28boolean%29) *may be used to ensure that the file exists as a precondition prior continuing to execute the tests, but this method can be replaced as desired.)*

Comment: @EricWilson I noticed that you [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7082818/revisions#rev0df14ebb-cc15-44f9-a4af-3173216b5ae5) the provided code sample yesterday. Did you have an opportunity to try it? If so, did it work?

Comment: I think this just might be a bad question. The code that you have offered works regardless of whether the above `<testResources>` tag is in my `pom.xml`. I thought briefly that your answer was helping me, but nothing has really changed.

Comment: Based on your questions and the [context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070611/how-to-configure-pom-for-strutstestcase-so-that-web-xml-is-found) you provided, it sounded like you don't need to use `<testResources>`; you only need to access those _files_ during your tests, but they don't need to be on the test _classpath_, as the `<testResource>` configuration enables. I'll provide a new answer assuming you need these .xml files to be on the test classpath. Otherwise, the approach I suggested should answer your question describing how you can access these xml files from your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the path to the xml files to include them in the path for your tests.

Try:

```
<testResource>
   <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
   <includes>
      <include>*.xml</include>
   </includes>
</testResource>
```

Comment: Hmm . . . my webapp directory is not in main.

Comment: It should be as indicated above if you are following "The Maven Way".

Comment: To clarify, @SingleShot's reference to "The Maven Way" is the [_Maven Standard Directory Layout_](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Also, although it is recommended that your web content be placed in `src/main/webapp` as discussed here, this shouldn't have an effect on your question.